# How can I make an exception for KeyError

Tags: python, keyerror, google-custom-search, try-except

I'm trying to make a program to uinterface with the Google CSE API, iterate over a list of people with companies, and pull LinkedIn profile information from the structured data. It then runs a regex to pull information from those and append them to a text file. Testing it works up to a point, but once I reach a certain name in the list, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\svillamil\Desktop\CSE2.py", line 27, in <module>
    results = google_search("Gene Grochala Capital Health", my_api_key, my_cse_id, num=1)
  File "C:\Users\svillamil\Desktop\CSE2.py", line 17, in google_search
    return res['items']
KeyError: 'items'
```

Investigating it on the CSE show that the name and company yield no results. So, I put the made an exception for the KeyError.

```
except KeyError:
    pass
```

This did not work, so I tried:

```
except Exception as e:
    pass
```

and even:

```
except:
    pass
```

with no luck.

Is there something wrong with my code that's stopping this error from passing? Or could it be an issue with the initial input?

Here is my program for reference:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import pprint
import csv
import re
import time
import os

os.chdir('C:\\users\\name\\Desktop')

my_api_key = "xxxxx"

my_cse_id = "xxxxx"

def google_search(search_term, api_key, cse_id, **kwargs):
    service = build("customsearch","v1",developerKey=api_key)#initializes an instance of the custom search service with the build module.
    res = service.cse().list(q=search_term, cx=cse_id, **kwargs).execute()#executes cse().list() on service to return metadata on the search performed, the specific CSE it is calling, and any other variable that might be added when calling the function as a whole
    return res['items']

a = 0

with open('list.csv', 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
                a+=1
                name = row[1] + ' ' + row[2] + ' at ' +row[4]
                print("This trial will search for", name)
                results = google_search(name, my_api_key, my_cse_id, num=1)
                try:
                        for result in results:
                                fn = r"fn':\s'(.+?)'"
                                pt = r"pagemap':.+'title.+?\s'(.*?)'"
                                role = r"role':\W+(.+?)'"
                                org = r"org\W+(.+?)'"
                                with open("cse_result.txt", "a+") as nameLookup:
                                        if re.search(str(fn),str(result)) is not None:
                                                name2 = re.search(str(fn),str(result)).group(1)
                                                nameLookup.write("Trial "+str(a)+'\n')
                                                nameLookup.write("The name being searched for in this trial is "+name+'.\n')
                                                nameLookup.write("The name found is "+str(name2)+"\n")
                                                nameLookup.write('\n')                                        
                                        else:
                                                nameLookup.write("Trial "+str(a)+'\n')
                                                nameLookup.write("We could not find a name on this trial."+'\n')
                                                nameLookup.write('\n')
                                        if re.search(str(pt),str(result)) is not None:
                                                position_title = re.search(str(pt),str(result)).group(1)
                                                nameLookup.write("The position found at this trial is " + position_title + '.\n')
                                                nameLookup.write('\n')
                                        else:
                                                nameLookup.write('We could not find a position title at this trial.')
                                                nameLookup.write('\n')
                                        if re.search(str(role),str(result)) is not None:
                                                role_title = re.search(str(role),str(result)).group(1)
                                                nameLookup.write("The position found at this trial is " + role_title + '.\n')
                                                nameLookup.write('\n')
                                        else:
                                                nameLookup.write('We could not return a position at this trial.')
                                                nameLookup.write('\n')
                                        if re.search(str(org),str(result)) is not None:
                                                orginization = re.search(str(org),str(result)).group(1)
                                                nameLookup.write("The orginization found at this trial is " + orginization + '.\n')
                                                nameLookup.write('\n')
                                        else:
                                                nameLookup.write('We could not return an orginization at this trial.')
                                                nameLookup.write('\n')
                                        nameLookup.write('\n')
                                        nameLookup.write('==========================')
                                        nameLookup.write('\n')
                except KeyError:
                        pass

                #time.sleep(1)
```

This still yielded the same error

=======================================================

Here is an edited code some changes based on the comments

```
def google_search(search_term, api_key, cse_id, **kwargs):
        service = build("customsearch","v1",developerKey=api_key)#initializes an instance of the custom search service with the build module.
        res = service.cse().list(q=search_term, cx=cse_id, **kwargs).execute()#executes cse().list() on service to return metadata on the search performed, the specific CSE it is calling, and any other variable that might be added when calling the function as a whole
        return res.get('items', [])

a = 0

def is_empty(any_structure):
        if any_structure:
                return False
        else:
                return True

with open('list.csv', 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
                a+=1
                name = row[1] + ' ' + row[2] + ' at ' +row[4]
                print("This trial will search for", name)
                results = google_search(name, my_api_key, my_cse_id, num=1)
                for result in results:
                        fn = r"fn':\s'(.+?)'"
                        pt = r"pagemap':.+'title.+?\s'(.*?)'"
                        role = r"role':\W+(.+?)'"
                        org = r"org\W+(.+?)'"
                        with open("cse_result.txt", "a+") as nameLookup:
                                if is_empty(result)==True:
                                        nameLookup.write('We could not return any data at this trial. Please see linkedin. This is trial '+a)
                                        nameLookup.write('\n')
                                if re.search(str(fn),str(result)) is not None:
                                        name2 = re.search(str(fn),str(result)).group(1)
                                        nameLookup.write("Trial "+str(a)+'\n')
                                        nameLookup.write("The name being searched for in this trial is "+name+'.\n')
                                        nameLookup.write("The name found is "+str(name2)+"\n")
                                        nameLookup.write('\n')                                        
                                else:
                                        nameLookup.write("Trial "+str(a)+'\n')
                                        nameLookup.write("We could not find a name on this trial."+'\n')
                                        nameLookup.write('\n')
                                if re.search(str(pt),str(result)) is not None:
                                        position_title = re.search(str(pt),str(result)).group(1)
                                        nameLookup.write("The position found at this trial is " + position_title + '.\n')
                                        nameLookup.write('\n')
                                else:
                                        nameLookup.write('We could not find a position title at this trial.')
                                        nameLookup.write('\n')
                                if re.search(str(role),str(result)) is not None:
                                        role_title = re.search(str(role),str(result)).group(1)
                                        nameLookup.write("The position found at this trial is " + role_title + '.\n')
                                        nameLookup.write('\n')
                                else:
                                        nameLookup.write('We could not return a position at this trial.')
                                        nameLookup.write('\n')
                                if re.search(str(org),str(result)) is not None:
                                        orginization = re.search(str(org),str(result)).group(1)
                                        nameLookup.write("The orginization found at this trial is " + orginization + '.\n')
                                        nameLookup.write('\n')
                                else:
                                        nameLookup.write('We could not return an orginization at this trial.')
                                        nameLookup.write('\n')
                                nameLookup.write('\n')
                                nameLookup.write('==========================')
                                nameLookup.write('\n')
```

The problem now is that it is not appending the notice that there is no data found if the dictionary object is empty.

Comment: I don't see `results = google_search(name, my_api_key, my_cse_id, num=1)` inside the `try..except`.  It looks like its just outside it.

Comment: The `try-except` should be for `return res['items']` inside the `google_search` function definition.

Comment: You should only `try/except` code that could raise an error. It's best not to wrap large blocks of code around it as you it is then no longer clear what code you are error handling.

Comment: If it's a dictionary, you could use [**`get`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) with a default parameter: `return res.get('items', [])` so it returns an empty list if the key doesn't exist.

Comment: @Abdou When I tried to wrap return res['items'] in the definition, I got a typeerror: nonetype is noniterable. I then did except (KeyError, TypeError) as e:, which led to another key error.

Comment: @PeterWood Your method does technically work, but it does not write to the text file to show that no input was found.  I edited the code to reflect some changes, which include a function to check if an object is empty, and an if statement just under open to append a notice to the text file.

Comment: @SVill, you're dealing with a fair number of issues here: just because you've wrapped the `return` statement with a `try-catch` does not mean that if you return a `None`, your program is going to play just fine with it. It seems that you're returning a `None` which is being looped through somewhere down the script and that's causing the `ypeerror: nonetype is noniterable`.